# mini cart subtotal update in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, mini-cart

I need to update the mini cart subtoal after removing the item through observer.
The event I used to remove item is **checkout_cart_save_after**

**Removing the item(s) works, but updating the mini-cart subtotal does not.**

[image]

observer code:

```
public function removeItems(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
$configSkuValue = 'test'; //product SKU need to be removed
$cart = $observer->getCart();
$quote = $observer->getCart()->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $items) {
    $sku = $items->getSku();
    if($sku == $configSkuValue && $quote->getSubtotal() < 35){
        $cart->removeItem($items->getId())->save();
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $data->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
        session_write_close();
    }
}
}
```

If the quantity is reduced via mini-cart, then the product is deleted if the condition meet's but subtotal is not updating . It's updating only after page load

Can anyone suggest me the way to update subtotal without page load

Comment: Neenga ena kekringa purilaye.....Apdi reload aagama update aganumna ajax thana use pananum...magento 1.9 default ah ve apdithana work aagum...

Comment: If we reduce the qty of product through mini-cart and if the sub total < than 35 and also if cart has a product with SKU 'test', then  I'm using this observer to remove that product programmaticaly. In that situation the sub total is not updating in mini cart once after page load it's updating properly